# Current state of the art for UTF-8 handling in a browser making an external post

Tags: javascript, utf-8, google-drive-api

I have an application with a browser page that allows upload of CSV to Google Drive via V2 of the api. It is only handling ASCII (I get "failed to execute btoa / string to be encoded contains characters outside the Latin1 range").

I've updated my code so that the content-type is now `"text/csv;charset=UTF-8;"`.  I am still using content-transfer-encoding of `base64`.

In multiple places on the web, I found recommendations of using `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)))`.  Previously, the code was only doing `btoa(data)`. It seems to work, though I have not tested it exhaustively.

I understand that `unescape` is considered in a precarious light relative to ECMA-262.  Here are the questions:

- a) does the above work for all of UTF-8 (including 4-byte chars)?
- b) if not, will it just fail to encode properly, or will I get a browser
  error?
- c) are there any other risks of using this approach (even if
  it handles 4-byte chars)?
- d) is there a better / newer way of doing this? I probably have the luxury of not supporting older browsers.

Comment: State of the art is not try changing the "encoding of strings" in JavaScript. Encoding should happen when the string is serialised to bits and bytes, and will work fine by default.

Comment: "*a browser page that allows upload of CSV*" - where exactly are you getting the CSV from? Are you generating it from data in your script?

Comment: The browser page contains a table of data, which may have non-ASCII characters.

Comment: And where does that table come from? Is it part of the static html served by the backend of your app?

Comment: yes, it is static html served by the backend

Comment: Why do you need to upload static data to Google Drive? .oO Regardless, please post the code that extracts the data from the html, converts it to CSV format, and makes the http request.

Comment: Can you provide your sample script for replicating your issue of `I get "failed to execute btoa / string to be encoded contains characters outside the Latin1 range"`?